# Any suggestion on following memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing application using nav-controlller. It shows me leak when i push the view in next view as i shown below in image. Please help me to find out leak resolution. Even i released next view object than after it show me leak as i shown below. If you need more screen shot or detail than please let me know.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ActivityUpdateiPad *updateactivity = [[ActivityUpdateiPad alloc]initWithNibName:@"ActivityUpdateiPad" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:updateactivity animated:YES];
    [updateactivity release];
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you release the controller after the push?

Comment: without any code is hard to help, can you provide the code of the 2 views?

Comment: looks fine, maybe you are doing some other operation on the selected row and that operations are leaking.

Comment: nope, i don't do anything else accept that.

Comment: There is a problem in releasing the object. It might be a possiblity that the source of crash is some where else rather than this point.

Comment: Can you check your ActivityUpdateiPad: init, viewDidLoad, viewWill.., viewDid... methods for some leaks. It is possible that somthing is going wrong there

Comment: @alinoz: I started working on it...I also think that might be problem.